# Example how to test twisted AMP

Tags: python, twisted, asynchronous-messaging-protocol

I am trying to figure out how to write unit tests for Twisted AMP, but I seem to be failing. I checked the source code, but it's quite overwhelming.

Can anyone write or point me to an example of testing simple AMP protocol sending data and receiving data via responder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Game uses AMP and has full test covage.](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~game-hackers/game/trunk/view/head:/game/test/test_network.py)

Comment: Great, thank you! Anywhere I can read up on curly braces in docstrings? Like `L{Value}` - saw it in the Game and Twisted tests.

Comment: It's called epytext: http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epytext.html.  pydoctor consumes it too: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pydoctor/0.4